# How to delete a photo permanently in group chat for all participants

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

How to delete a photo permanently in group chat, where I'm not the owner of the group chat. If I was an Admin of this group chat can I delete that photo permanently?

My friend sent photo of mine to group chat. After a few people saw it I told him to delete that photo, but when he deleted the photo in group chat I still see it. If he deleted photo in group chat before everyone saw it will the people who didn't see it still see that photo? When he deleted the photo 6 people saw it, but the rest didn't see yet. Will they be able to see it when they open it?

Answer (score 2):

Once a message sent, you can not unsend it nor can you delete any message from recipient's inbox.

From [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/227699513911093):

> No, sent messages can't be unsent or removed from the person's inbox. Depending on the person's notification settings, they may also receive your message as an email notification.

Here is a way you can give try:
Ask your friend to mark that picture as *spam* from his/her sent message. After marking spam or abusive that messages will not be readable to recipient(s).

Answer (score 1):

When a message is sent through Facebook and delivered it cannot be taken back. Once it reaches the recipient(s) it is there until they remove it from their message log.

Comment: SO, that's mean we can't delete it permanently. they're still see.and there is now way to make it disappear ,right?

Comment: It is "gone" once everyone removes it from their individual message logs.